# Excel - how to have Multiple Input Devices (USB)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

How do I differentiate between 2 USB input devices that are both placing data into the spreadsheet?

I have 2 USB calipers that input their current measurements as if they were keystrokes. The data is sent to excel (or any program really) and placed vertically. Currently, Excel treats both calipers as if they were the same instrument.

What I would like to have is the two calipers record their data into distinct areas of the excel spreadsheet.

An example would be Tool 1 and Tool 2 are both being used simultaneously by two different people while both connected to the same computer. Tool 1 will always put its data in the following areas: (A1,B1,C1, A2,B2,C2 ... etc.)  Tool 2 will record its data into the following areas: (A5,B5,C5, A6,B6,C6 ... etc.)  The data does not have to go into the same sheet, it can be in different sheets or whatever is easiest.

Can anyone help?

---

<sup>**updated to include content originally provided as an *answer***</sup>
A few questions:

1) Where can I find the information for the "Scripting.FileSystemObject"?  I assume this line needs to be replaced with an identifier for each of the individual usb tools. In device manager they are listed as HID Keyboards but I see no identifying number.

2) Do I just copy-paste the above three sets of code into the VBA under Sheet1 for USB1 and Sheet2 for USB2, or do they need to be placed in individual macros?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your USB devices simply register as Human Interface Devices and sent their output to any application that is currently in focus.

If that is the case, this is not trivial. Windows will merge all keyboard inputs into one input stream, there's usually no way to distinguish from which keyboard (or keyboard-like device) the input came.

That being said, there appears to be a raw input api that lets you catch input per device: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawinput.aspx

In theory, you should be able to interface this API in VBA, but you have to decide if its worth the effort. The *far* simpler way is to use two computers.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set up the sources as separate objects and the output sheets as objects. Then each object can be handled separately or any way you choose.

EG USB1 should have a different filepath to USB2. Also each workbook can be an object, each sheet can be an object a range within each sheet can be an object

Eg USB1

```
Dim objFs1 As Object, objF1 As Object, objF1 As Object, objFc1 As Object
Set objFs1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objF1 = objFs1.GetFolder(strFilePath)
Set objFc1 = objF1.Files
```

USB2

```
Dim objFs2 As Object, objF2 As Object, objF2 As Object, objFc2 As Object
Set objFs2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objF2 = objFs2.GetFolder(strFilePath)
Set objFc2 = objF2.Files
```

Not sure how you want to load set USB objects but one possibility is to use something like the file dialog to select a file/folder

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Show

If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
    End
End If

For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
    strEndofPath = InStrRev(.SelectedItems(lngCount), "\")
    strFilePath = Left(.SelectedItems(lngCount), strEndofPath)
    strFilename = Right(.SelectedItems(lngCount), Len(.SelectedItems(lngCount)) - strEndofPath)
Next lngCount
End With
```

Write Objects for excel

```
Dim objWB1 As Workbook, objSheet1 As Worksheet, rngArea1 as Range
Dim objWB2 As Workbook, objSheet2 As Worksheet, rngArea2 as Range
```

Comment: Apologies - this is only an example method to handle multiple devices. The "Scripting.FileSystemObject" is more suited to USB drives rather than devices. Does your device come with support or drivers? The functions to access and control a HID device are included in the Windows hid.dll which is located in the System32 folder - Try this [Link](http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/category/usb-hid-library/#hid-class)